# The entities in calling "line" variable is a string , but when I call "scores" variable it becomes numeric ,Can anyone explain?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, floating-point, jupyter-notebook

```
n = int(input())       //to get input for n entries
student_marks = {}            //dictionary for storing key value pair
for _ in range(n):
    line = (input().split())            //line for getting the entries
    name, scores = line[0], line[1:]
    scores = list(map(float, scores))
    student_marks[name] = scores               //storing in in dictionary
```

The entities in calling "line" variable is a string , but when I call "scores" variable it becomes numeric.please explain how is that possible because I should get some error in it of converting the values into numeric while applying float function.

**sample Input :**

1
raj 32 43 32

Comment: For the input that you provided, you must get `ValueError`. Do you mean you are _not_ getting it?

Comment: yes it working fine , I am not getting any error! ,It should some error like "float function not supported on strings"

Comment: Consider printing `scores` before passing the variable to `list(map...`. What is printed?

Comment: I checked that to , when you call score variable : its printing : ['32' ,'43' , '32']

Comment: Dint get you ! My query why its not showing error when applying float function on strings.

Comment: Your strings, as printed, are numeric. Why there should be an error if you apply `float` to them? Now, at second glance, your program behaves precisely as expected.

Comment: yes ! I got this finally , its not about only string , it was a numeric string actually.